# Titchmarsh divisor problem

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I have trouble to conclude what I have to prove for this exercice.

Let $$ c(a) = \frac{\varphi(a)}{a} \prod_{ p \not\mid a} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \right) $$

Prove that
$$ \sum_{a < p \leq x } \tau(p-a) = c(a) x + O\left( x \frac{ \log \log x}{\log x} \right) $$

Hint:
Use Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem and also that for $(a,q)=1$ we have
$ \pi(x;q,a) \ll \frac{x}{\varphi(q) \log (x/q) } $ and also
$$ \sum_{n \leq x; (n,a)=1} \frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = c(a) x + O(\tau(a)\log x) $$

**What I did**:

Since $ \tau(n) = 2 \sum_{ d \mid n , d < n^{1/2}} 1 + s(n) $ where $s(n)=1$ if is a perfect square and 0 otherwise we have
$$ \sum_{a < p \leq x } \tau(p-a) =  2 \sum_{d < x^{1/2}, (d,a) = 1} ( \pi(x;d,a) - \pi(a+d^2; d, a) ) + O(x^{1/2}) = \star $$
Then using the hint we have that
$$ \sum_{d < x^{1/2}, (d,a) =1} \pi(a+d^2; d, a)  \ll  \sum_{d < x^{1/2}, (d,a) =1} \frac{ a +d^2}{\varphi(d) \log ( (a+d^2)/d)} \ll  \frac{ a+ x}{ \log( (a+x)/x^{1/2}) } $$
$$ \ll x/ \log x $$
hence, by Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem we have
$$ \star = 2 \operatorname{Li}(x) \left( \sum_{d \leq x^{1/2} (\log x)^{-B}; (d,a)=1} \frac{1}{\varphi(d)} \right) + 2\sum_{x^{1/2} (\log x)^{-B} < d < x^{1/2}, (d,a)=1} \pi(x;d,a) + O(x/\log x) $$

$$ = 2 \operatorname{Li}(x) \left( \sum_{d \leq x^{1/2} (\log x)^{-B}; (d,a)=1} \frac{1}{\varphi(d)} \right) + O \left( \frac{x}{\log x} + \sum_{x^{1/2} (\log x)^{-B} < d < x^{1/2}, (d,a)=1} \pi(x;d,a) \right) $$

Now in some way **i want to show that**
$$2 \operatorname{Li}(x) \left( \sum_{d \leq x^{1/2} (\log x)^{-B}; (d,a)=1} \frac{1}{\varphi(d)} \right) = c(a) x $$
and that
$$ O \left( \frac{x}{\log x} + \sum_{x^{1/2} (\log x)^{-B} < d < x^{1/2}, (d,a)=1} \pi(x;d,a) \right) = O\left( x \frac{ \log \log x}{\log x} \right) $$

**But i don't know how**. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reciprocal sum of $1/\varphi(d)$, partial summation shall give

$$
\sum_{\substack{d\le x\\(d,a)=1}}{1\over\varphi(d)}=c(a)\log x+O(1),
$$

which indicates that

\begin{aligned}
2\operatorname{Li}(x)\sum_{\substack{d\le x^{1/2}(\log x)^{-B}\\(d,a)=1}}{1\over\varphi(d)}
&=c(a){2x\over\log x}\log(x^{1/2}\log^{-B}x)+O\left(x\over\log x\right) \\
&=c(a)x+O\left(x\log\log x\over\log x\right).
\end{aligned}

For the second part, apply the Brun-Titchmarsh inequality (i.e. $\pi(x;q,a)\ll{x\over\varphi(q)\log(x/q)}$), so that

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{x^{1/2}(\log x)^{-B}<d\le x^{1/2}\\(d,a)=1}}\pi(x;d,a)
&\ll{x\over\log x}\sum_{x^{1/2}(\log x)^{-B}<d\le x^{1/2}}{1\over\varphi(d)} \\
&\ll{x\over\log x}\log{x^{1/2}\over x^{1/2}(\log x)^{-B}}\ll{x\log\log x\over\log x}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Actually we have that $ \sum_{d \leq x, (d,a)=1} 1/\varphi(d) = c(a) \log x + c_1(a) + O(\tau(a)x^{-1} \log x) $ but actually i don't get how to prove it, that is more accurate than $c(a) \log x + O(1) $

Comment: @3m0o You might get some hints from the tricks used in the proof for $\sum_{n\le x}\frac1n=\log x+\gamma+O(1/x)$.